# Superfish dropdown clipped by table bounds

Tags: jquery, css, superfish, suckerfish

I am having a problem using Superfish dropdowns inside a jQuery grid. It looks like the dropdown is being clipped by the table bounds.

I’ve researched this and it seems to be a z-index issue except that I have tried various combinations of z-index to no avail.

Here’s a screenshot of what it looks like:
[image]

I can post the css and code if need be; it's a bit complicated though.

Thanks in advance.

Rick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe adding overflow:visible; to the parent element of your dropdown?

Comment: That was the hint I needed. My two-column stylesheet had overflow set to hidden. Changing it to visible worked. Thank you!